# Features of phosphatase

Tags: biochemistry

I was wondering if you would be able to help me with discovering what the main regulatory feature of a phosphatase is. I understand many have separate catalytic and regulatory subunits, however, so do kinases so I feel that there is a different answer that I am not understanding. Thank you,

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. What do you mean by feature?

Comment: there are LOTS of different phosphatases - and LOTS of different regulatory   mechanisms - this is too unclear of a question

Comment: Maybe OP is asking about the role of phosphorylation/dephosphorylation in signal-transduction by covalent modification.

Comment: I answered assuming the OP was unclear about the difference between phosphatases and kinases, based on the statement "I understand many have separate catalytic and regulatory subunits, however, so do kinases" - that seems to suggest that the OP thought kinases and phosphatases did the same thing and that OP was looking for how they differed from a regulatory standpoint.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I'm not familiar with the specifics of the catalytic activity anymore, and you may very well be correct, but from a regulatory perspective the modified protein doesn't much care about the extra water. :) But importantly: phosphorylase and phosphatase are not the same at all, and phosphorylase does not cleave phosphate, so I think you have a typo in the comment since it seems clear you are meaning to talk about phosphatase.

Comment: @BryanKrause Ahhh. it is purely typing error I'm very sorry. That would be phosphatase. I did it completely subconsciously because plausibly then I was reading some article on phosphorylase in wikipedia.

Comment: I'm deleting that comment and copy-pasting and correcting it so that people do not get misguided.

Comment: @BryanKrause as I had been taught, there is a basic difference between working mechanism of kinase and phosphatase... kinase do not release H2O when it adds phosphate to something. But Phosphatase takes H2O (i.e. hydrolysis) when it cleaves the phosphate... i.e. their work is not the exact reverse.

Comment: @WYSIWYG. firstly: a. that is a trick question... features are defined according to the object definitions in a given standard, and definitions of the past may be obsolete, for example a feature may be a field in a .gff3 file, or a .gff2 file, or see this example glossary, in accordance with the EnsEMBL database schema: https://www.vectorbase.org/glossary; b. how do you maintain so many posts, are you a bot?

Answer (score 3):

Kinases phosphorylate, or *add* a phosphate group.

Phosphatases *remove* a phosphate group.

Beyond that, the concepts for regulating them are the same, though the precise factors of course are different.